# flutter bloc to childs

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Here is the main page:

```
child: BlocProvider(
    create: (_) => WelcomeCubit(context.read<AuthenticationRepository>()),
    child:
        WelcomeForm(),
```

And in the WelcomeForm

```
return BlocListener<WelcomeCubit, WelcomeState>(listener: (context, state) {
  print("BlocListener " + state.status.toString());                                                 
     if (state is newPage){
       Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => BlocProvider<WelcomeCubit>.value(
                  value: welcomeCubit,
                  child: SmsVerifyPage(),
                ))); }
```

On the SmsVerifyPage :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SizeConfig().init(context);
return BlocBuilder<WelcomeCubit, WelcomeState>(
  buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.otp != current.otp,
  builder: (context, state) {
    print(state.status.toString());
  >  print(state.phone.value); /////// <--------------- this value is always null.
    return Scaffold();}
```

I may be trying wrong at this point, I guess. but I couldn't find a solution to solve this. I referred all flutter bloc recipes but in vain I couldn't find one.

Thanks for any solution and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The `BlocBuilder` tries to find an instance of `WelcomeCubit` using the context provided. The context here comes from your `Navigator` which is an ancestor of your `WelcomeForm` so there is no `WelcomeCubit` available using that context. One solution to this problem is to wrap `MaterialApp` (which provides root navigator) with your `BlocProvider`.